# Find the value of the triple integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the volume limited by the surfaces $x^2+y^2=4$, $z=0$, together with the portion of the plane $z=x-y$ with $z\ge 0$.

So, I've drawn the region of integration and calculated the following integral: $$\int_{\frac{-3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{r(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)}(r)\, dz\,dr\,d\theta$$

The problem I'm having is that this integral has a value of $0$. Can anybody see where is my mistake?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say

$\int_{\frac{-3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{r(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)}r\, dz\,dr\,d\theta=\int_{\frac{-3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_{0}^{2} r^2(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)\, dr\,d\theta=\frac{8}{3}\int_{\frac{-3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (\cos\theta-\sin\theta)\,d\theta=$

$=\frac{8}{3}[\sin\theta+\cos\theta]_{\frac{-3\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{8}{3}(\sqrt{2}-(-\sqrt{2})=\cdots $